# How do I avoid selected item for multiple select dropdown using PrimeNG Dropdown?

Tags: angular, primeng

I have three dropdown, each of the dropdown are related to each other, They should not have any selected value in any of three dropdown.

For e.g
I have three dropdown like Stock 1, Stock 2, Stock 3.
If I have selected a value for Stock 1 then that value won't be able to select from Stock 2 & Stock 3.

I would like to achieve above functionality using PrimeNG Dropdown in Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In html

```
<p-dropdown [options]="stockDropdown1" [(ngModel)]="selectedStock1" (onChange)="stock1ChangeHandler()"></p-dropdown>
<p-dropdown [options]="stockDropdown2" [(ngModel)]="selectedStock2" (onChange)="stock2ChangeHandler()"></p-dropdown>
```

In ts:

```
completeStockDropdown = [{label:'choice1', value:foo}, {label:'choice2', value:bar}];
stockDropdown1 = this.completeStockDropdown;
stockDropdown2 = this.completeStockDropdown;

stock1ChangeHandler() {
    this.stockDropdown2 = this.completeStockDropdown.filter(option => option.value!=this.selectedStock1);
}
```

Comment: Can we do the same functionality using **AutoComplete** ?